# View become white when I Click away Smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk, visualworks

Hello so I have a Main application that draw a Circle and a rectangle but when I click away they juste disappear here is the code I use

```
initialize
shapesView := ShapesView new.
shapesModel := ShapesModel new.
shapesView model: shapesModel.
```

and I have the component initialisation in

```
postOpenWith: aBuilder
shapesView initializeComponents.
```

in the ShapesView class I have aModel accessor and this methode , my Model and controller are still empty

```
initializeComponents
| shape gc|
gc := self graphicsContext.
gc paint: ColorValue red.
shape := MyRectangle origin: 2@2 extent: 50@75.
shape displayFilledOn: gc.
gc paint: ColorValue blue.
shape := MyCircle center: 100@100 radius: 50.
shape displayFilledOn: gc.
```

Comment: Is this VisualWorks Smalltalk? My guess is that you must put the drawing code into a method that is called regularly, not only once when the view is initialized. If I skimmed http://www.cincomsmalltalk.com/main/documentation/VisualWorks/GUIDevGuide.pdf correctly, you should override `displayOn:` in ShapesView.

Comment: It seems Dolphin. Anyway, you should tell which Smalltalk dialect you are using (and ad a tag for it) in order to get a good answer

Comment: well the issue was that in one hand I needed to override the     displayOn: and in the other hand I needed to invalidate the model at the right time to theese shapes don't vanish when there is an other action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you found, for the shapes to be persistent, the drawing should be in a 
"displayOn: gc"  method (as JayK mentioned) in the ShapeView class (instance side), which should do the drawing you specify:
gc paint: ColorValue red.

shape := MyRectangle origin: 2@2 extent: 50@75.

shape displayFilledOn: gc.

gc paint: ColorValue blue.

shape := MyCircle center: 100@100 radius: 50.

shape displayFilledOn: gc.

The shapes could be created in an intializeComponents, but the api calls displayOn: whenever a re-display of the view is needed.
Changing the model or resizing the window will cause an invalidation and  re-display.
hth - Arden Thomas

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to find out which method is being sent when the UI Element is gaining focus again.
How this is done varies from Smalltalk dialect to dialect.
The way, you have implemented this now just means you just draw it once.
This does not mean it is being redrawn at all.